# While loop to move a shape from a point to point

Tags: java

Still young in Java and currently try to figure out how to move a shape through the drawing area. I want the shape move through the line however it end up with a long line. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
int x = 10;

while (x < 100) 
{
    repaint();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(x, x, 10, 10);
    repaint();
    x += 1;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK - repaint is not the same as clear. You need to look through API and find appropriate method to clear previous drawings.

Comment: I haven't used AWT/Swing for a long time. May be your code executes too quickly for your eyes to notice the shape move. Add a pause of desired amount of time to see the shape move.

Comment: @Dmitry Is there any suggestion regard the function? I not sure how to search on it and i cannot found one to clear the previous drawings.

Comment: @vinay if it is just move too much I think the rectangle should just appear on first point and to the last point but not  a line constructed between the first and last point. Still i am not sure what is happening. Java just have too much function. @@

Comment: @TryToProgram Yes what you said is true. You might want to clear previous rectangle using clearRect method. But again moving fast is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GUI that moves the image across the drawing panel.

[image: Image Move]

First we create the model classes of Leg and Journey.  These classes keep track of the rectangle we want to move across the screen.  We give each leg of the journey a name and a delay.

Next, we create a drawing panel from a JPanel.  We place the drawing panel in a JFrame.  This is the view.

Finally, we create a Runnable that gets a journey leg and draws the rectangle on the drawing panel.  This is the controller.

Looking at the paintComponent method of the drawing panel, we see that the method code does nothing but paint.  The control code of what to paint is in the Runnable.

Here's the complete, runnable code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageMove implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JourneyRunnable journeyRunnable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageMove());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Move");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        journeyRunnable = new JourneyRunnable(drawingPanel, new Journey());
        new Thread(journeyRunnable).start();
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        journeyRunnable.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8498462824787395933L;

        private int xPos, yPos, width, height;

        private Leg leg;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.width = 100;
            this.height = 50;
            this.xPos = 0;
            this.yPos = (200 - height) / 2;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        }

        public void setLeg(Leg leg) {
            this.leg = leg;
            this.xPos += 10;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);

            if (leg != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                centerString(g, new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height),
                        leg.getName(), g.getFont());
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method centers a <code>String</code> in a bounding
         * <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * 
         * @param g
         *            - The <code>Graphics</code> instance.
         * @param r
         *            - The bounding <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * @param s
         *            - The <code>String</code> to center in the bounding
         *            rectangle.
         * @param font
         *            - The display font of the <code>String</code>
         * 
         * @see java.awt.Graphics
         * @see java.awt.Rectangle
         * @see java.lang.String
         */
        private void centerString(Graphics g, Rectangle r, String s, Font font) {
            FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

            Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
            int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
            int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
            int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
            int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

            int a = (r.width / 2) - (rWidth / 2) - rX;
            int b = (r.height / 2) - (rHeight / 2) - rY;

            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(s, r.x + a, r.y + b);
        }
    }

    public class JourneyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private boolean running;

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        private Journey journey;

        public JourneyRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel, Journey journey) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
            this.journey = journey;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                Leg leg = journey.getLeg();
                setLeg(leg);
                sleep(leg);
            }
        }

        private void setLeg(final Leg leg) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawingPanel.setLeg(leg);
                }
            });
        }

        private void sleep(Leg leg) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(leg.getDelay());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

    public class Journey {

        private int index;
        private List<Leg> legs;

        public Journey() {
            this.legs = new ArrayList<>();

            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 1", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 2", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 3", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 4", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 5", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 6", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 7", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 8", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 9", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 10", 1000L));

            this.index = 0;
        }

        public Leg getLeg() {
            Leg leg = legs.get(index);
            index = ++index % legs.size();
            return leg;
        }
    }

    public class Leg {
        private final String name;
        private final long delay;

        public Leg(String name, long delay) {
            this.name = name;
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public long getDelay() {
            return delay;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, i have tried and it did works. Still I need some time to digest it because i am required to implement it on my drawing area. Anyway Thanks